# What are these four large snails doing?

Tags: behaviour, gastropod

Hiking in some hills near Taipei after a rain, I saw lots of large snails out and about. Here "large" means the shells are say 8 cm long, and the snail itself fully stretched out 10 to 15 cm perhaps.

At one point I saw a cluster of four snails stuck together in a confusing way. The one on the right was slowly climbing uphill, pulling the other three along.

What is going on here? I see some connections between some of the snails, but I can't really understand most of what I'm looking at here, nor why four snails would be stuck together sideways like this.

[image: four large snails doing something]

[image: four large snails doing something]

[image: four large snails doing something]

Comment: The middle two, at least, are having sex with their [love dart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_dart).

Comment: @vkehayas ouch!

Comment: thumb up for snails love

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are probably giant African snails, *Achatina fulica*, an invasive species of land snails. The two snails in the middle are mating using love darts. The other two may be waiting for their turn.

See also: [Wikipedia - Achatina fulica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achatina_fulica)

Comment: Yikes again! A top 100 invasive species, spreads human disease, *and* a delicacy according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissachatina_fulica).

Answer (score 0):

These snails, *Achatina fulica*, belong to a family of land snails called Achatinidae. They are invasive and while being agricultural pests, can also be vectors of pathogens. The two snails in the middle are actually mating through a reciprocal simultaneous exchange of gametes through the sexual organs that are clearly visible. These species of land snails do not use love darts as suggested by Dr. Evenor.

Comment: Please provide citations or other forms of evidence to support your answer.

Comment: As @theforestecologist indicates - for species ID answers we expect an image from a credible source that shows the IDd species and additional evidence is necessary, such as proof that the species indeed inhabits the region where it was spotted. etc.